# MUI X Date Picker v5 LocalizationProvider first day of week

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, date-fns, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I want to set localization in app different to user's localization, in a way that first day of the week is always Monday, while everything else can be set based on user's localization. I'm using MUI DatePicker and I tried bunch of options. Code below seems logical, but it's not working. I can replace `date-fns` with different library if I have to, but I would like to keep it if possible.

Relevant packages:

```js
{
   "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.130",
   "@mui/material": "^5.13.1",
   "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.4.0",
   "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.4.0",
   "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
}
```

`index.tsx`

```js
<React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <LocalizationProvider
        dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
        adapterLocale={{ options: { weekStartsOn: 1 } }}
      >
        <SettingsProvider>
          <CollapseDrawerProvider>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <App />
              <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
            </BrowserRouter>
          </CollapseDrawerProvider>
        </SettingsProvider>
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```